# Writing conditions in cakephp model associations hasMany and belongsTo

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, model-associations

Here is my database schema.
[image: Database Scheme]
In my employees controller I want to show employees belonging to particular dept 
if dept_no is passed or else show all employees.

Below is my options array. Currently it is showing all records with employees department name.

```
$options = array('contain' => array(
                   'DeptEmp' => array(
                       'fields' => array('DeptEmp.dept_no')
                    ),
                    'DeptEmp.Department' => array(
                       'fields' => array('Department.dept_name')
                    )
                )
           );
```

My Employee model

```
$hasMany = array(
            'DeptEmp' => array(
              'className' => 'DeptEmp',
              'foreignKey' => 'emp_no',
              'dependent' => false
             )
          );
```

My DeptEmp model

```
public $belongsTo=array(
                   'Employee'=>array(
                      'className'=>'Employee',
                      'foreignKey'=>'emp_id',
                      'dependent'=>false
                    ),
                    'Department'=>array(
                      'className'=>'Department',
                      'foreignKey'=>'dept_no',
                      'dependent'=>false
                    )
                 );
```

My Department model

```
public $hasMany = array(
                   'DeptEmp' => array(
                      'className' => 'DeptEmp',
                      'foreignKey' => 'dept_no',
                      'dependent' => false
                    )
                 );
```

I tried

```
$this->Employee->DeptEmp->dept_no ='d006'
```

but it does not have any effect.

Kindly guide me if I am doing something wrong since I am newbie to cakephp.

Answer (score 0):

Contain sadly doesn't do a join on anything but `hasOne` association, instead it does multiple queries, so any conditions that you do on the contained data won't filter the original model.

But you can do it the other way around: Finding `DeptEmp` whose `dept_no` is 'd006' and contain all `Employee` that are in the results.

Or do a joined find query, providing in your `$options` array the field `joins`.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to look again at your entity-relationship diagram. Managers are also employees. You really only need two main models: Employee and Department. Also best to use id column to identify records as you may wish to change dep_no for a department which would require updating dep_no in all employees of that department.

**Employee Model**

```
<?php

class Employee extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Employee';

/**
 * Model Schema
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
    protected $_schema = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 8, 'key' => 'primary'),
        'first_name' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false),
        'last_name' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false),
        'birth_date' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => false),
        'gender' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false),
        'hire_date' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => false),
        'department_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 8),
        'manager_id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 8),
        'created' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => false),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true, 'default' => null)
        );

/**
 * Model Associations
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Department' => array(
            'className'   => 'Department',
            'foreignKey'  => 'department_id',
            'dependent' => true
            ),
        );
```

**Department Model**

```
<?php

class Department extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Department';

/**
 * Model Schema
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
    protected $_schema = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'length' => 8, 'key' => 'primary'),
        'number' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 8),
        'name' => array('type' => 'string', 'null' => false),
        'created' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => false),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'datetime', 'null' => true, 'default' => null)
        );

/**
 * Model Associations
 *
 * @var array
 * @access public
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Employee' => array(
            'className'   => 'Employee',
            'foreignKey'  => 'department_id',
            'dependent'   => true
            )
        );
    public $hasOne = array(
        'DepartmentManager' => array(
            'className' => 'Employee',
            'foreignKey'  => 'department_id',
            'conditions' => array('DepartmentManager.manager_id' => null),
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

**Department Controller**

```
$data = $this->Department->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Department.number' => 'd006'),
    'contain' => array(
        'DepartmentManager', 'Employee',
        )
    ));
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Department] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [number] => d006
            [name] => Human Resources
            [created] => 2014-02-25 00:00:00
            [modified] =>
        )

    [DepartmentManager] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [first_name] => David
            [last_name] => Scott
            [birth_date] => 2014-02-25
            [gender] => M
            [hire_date] => 2014-02-25
            [department_id] => 1
            [manager_id] => 
            [created] => 2014-02-25 00:00:00
            [modified] => 
        )

    [Employee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [first_name] => David
                    [last_name] => Scott
                    [birth_date] => 2014-02-25
                    [gender] => M
                    [hire_date] => 2014-02-25
                    [department_id] => 1
                    [manager_id] => 
                    [created] => 2014-02-25 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [first_name] => Joe
                    [last_name] => Bloggs
                    [birth_date] => 2014-02-25
                    [gender] => M
                    [hire_date] => 2014-02-25
                    [department_id] => 1
                    [manager_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2014-02-25 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [first_name] => Jane
                    [last_name] => Bloggs
                    [birth_date] => 2014-02-25
                    [gender] => F
                    [hire_date] => 2014-02-25
                    [department_id] => 1
                    [manager_id] => 1
                    [created] => 2014-02-25 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Hope this is helpful.